# Having trouble with class scope

Tags: c++, berkeley-db

I have a class called Streamer. Here is Streamer.h

```
class Streamer {

public:
    Streamer(const MyDb& realtimeDb);
    virtual ~Streamer(void);

private:
    virtual void    callback_1(T_UPDATE pUpdate);
    virtual void    callback_2(Q_UPDATE pUpdate);
};
```

Here is Streamer.cpp

```
Streamer::Streamer(const MyDb& realtimeDb) {
}

Streamer::~Streamer(void) {
}

void Streamer::callback_1(T_UPDATE pUpdate) {
    // I need to do something with pUpdate and realtimeDb here, like this:
    // Getting a cursor from db (works fine in main.cpp, but not in callback)
    Dbc *cursorp;
    realtimeDb.getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0);
}

void Streamer::callback_2(Q_UPDATE pUpdate) {
    // I need to do something with pUpdate and realtimeDb here, like this:
    // Getting a cursor from db (works fine in main.cpp, but not in callback)
    Dbc *cursorp;
    realtimeDb.getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0);
}
```

Streamer has two methods that are callbacks from an API. I can't change these parameters. I do, however, need to access the database instance MyDb that I am passing to the constructor (am I even doing that right?). This is how I am passing it, from main.cpp:

```
MyDb realtimeDb(databasePath, databaseName);
Streamer streamer(realtimeDb);
```

When I try to access realtimeDb from one of the callbacks, I get:

```
error: 'realtimeDb' was not declared in this scope
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any errors before that one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a member variable in your class to store the reference that you pass it in the constructor. Currently, you are passing in a const reference to the object but the class does nothing with it. You need to store the details of the `MyDb` object as a member variable. This could be a reference, const reference, or pointer to an instance of `MyDb` but you need something so that your class can access it once it is created.

Something like

```
class Streamer {

public:
   Streamer(const MyDb& Db);
   virtual ~Streamer(void);

private:
   const MyDb& realtimeDb;
   virtual void    callback_1(T_UPDATE pUpdate);
   virtual void    callback_2(Q_UPDATE pUpdate);
};
```

then the constructor will be

```
Streamer::Streamer(const MyDb& Db) 
     : realtimeDb(Db)                // initialise the reference here
{
}
```

you could also use a pointer instead of a reference if you wanted although you would need to modify the member variable accordingly

Comment: Not knowing anything about C++, that sounds exactly like what I want to do. What does that look like?

Comment: Have a private member variable like `MyDb& m_database` which is a reference to a `MyDb` object and initialise it in the constructor with the argument to your constructor.

Comment: +1 So far this is the only answer that answers the question without changing the semantics of the code.

Comment: Ok, think I've almost got it. I'm getting this error `error: passing 'const MyDb' as 'this' argument of 'Db& MyDb::getDb()' discards qualifiers`

Comment: @nathancahill that sounds like an error with your `MyDb` class. You could try removing the `const` from your member variable and turn it into a regular reference. You would also need to change the argument to the constructor similarly (remove the const). Other than that I cannot say as this is a problem with a different class.

Comment: Got it!! Removing the const worked! Thanks! I had been working at this for two days now with no love. Can't tell you how happy I am with your answer.

Comment: @nathancahill ok good, but be careful with passing arguments via non const reference as it allows you to change the argument you are passing. I would recommend getting a good C++ book if you are totally new to C++ like you said.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really "class scope" you have, but constructor scope.

```
Streamer::Streamer(const MyDb& realtimeDb)
{
    //realtimeDb exists only here
}
```

You can do something like this:

streamer.h

```
class Streamer {

public:
    Streamer(const MyDb& realtimeDb);
    virtual ~Streamer(void);

private:
    MyDb* realtimeDb;
    virtual void    callback_1(T_UPDATE pUpdate);
    virtual void    callback_2(Q_UPDATE pUpdate);
};
```

streamer.cpp

```
Streamer::Streamer(const MyDb& realtimeDb) {
    this->realtimeDb = &realtimeDb;
}

Streamer::~Streamer(void) {
}

void Streamer::callback_1(T_UPDATE pUpdate) {
    // I need to do something with pUpdate and realtimeDb here, like this:
    // Getting a cursor from db (works fine in main.cpp, but not in callback)
    Dbc *cursorp;
    realtimeDb->getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0);
}

void Streamer::callback_2(Q_UPDATE pUpdate) {
    // I need to do something with pUpdate and realtimeDb here, like this:
    // Getting a cursor from db (works fine in main.cpp, but not in callback)
    Dbc *cursorp;
    realtimeDb->getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0);
}
```

This way realtimeDb pointer will exist everywhere in the class scope, so every non-static method can access it.

But, because it's a pointer, syntax will be different.

Also, be careful - if someone declares Streamer with default constructor, realtimeDb will be NULL, and callbacks will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: So once I add `MyDb* realtimeDb;` to `private` and `this->realtimeDb = &realtimeDb;` to the constructor, I can access the passed instance from the callbacks?

Comment: You could do the same with the reference, but you should be consistent with the const-ness.

Comment: This seems to work, but I get this error: `error: request for member 'getDb' in '((Streamer*)this)->Streamer::realtimeDb', which is of non-class type 'MyDb*'`

Comment: This code uses pointers, so instead of `realtimeDb.getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0); ` use `realtimeDb->getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Your realtimeDb is defined as an argument of your constructor, but it's not defined in the callbacks.

What you probably want to do is to keep the reference to that object, like this:

```
class Streamer {

public:
    Streamer(MyDb& realtimeDb); // I doubt you need the "const"...
    virtual ~Streamer(void);

private:
    virtual void    callback_1(T_UPDATE pUpdate);
    virtual void    callback_2(Q_UPDATE pUpdate);
    MyDb& m_realtimeDb;
};
```

And your implementation:

```
Streamer::Streamer(const MyDb& realtimeDb) : m_realtimeDb(realtimeDb) {
}

Streamer::~Streamer(void) {
}

void Streamer::callback_1(T_UPDATE pUpdate) {
    // I need to do something with pUpdate and realtimeDb here, like this:
    // Getting a cursor from db (works fine in main.cpp, but not in callback)
    Dbc *cursorp;
    m_realtimeDb.getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0);
}

void Streamer::callback_2(Q_UPDATE pUpdate) {
    // I need to do something with pUpdate and realtimeDb here, like this:
    // Getting a cursor from db (works fine in main.cpp, but not in callback)
    Dbc *cursorp;
    m_realtimeDb.getDb().cursor(NULL, &cursorp, 0);
}
```